# hadoop pig - loading float with commas

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a csv file  full of float numbers encoded with a comma rather than a dot.
I made a pig loading script precising the float type, but when reading the comma, pig can"t convert that to a float (he expect float to have dots).

How could I change the commas by dot in the loading phase ? 
I understand a UDF could make the trick, but is there another simpler way ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some sample input?

Comment: Not really as I don't have internet access from my owrkplace :-(

Comment: What's the separator for the csv? Not comma I assume? In that case you might be able to load as string, do a replacement of comma for dot using Pig, then cast to float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, tested this just for fun with some simple data:

```
1,2;2,3;4,5
5,6;6,7;7,8
```

Pig script:

```
data = load 'commatest.csv' using PigStorage(';') as (f1:chararray, f2:chararray, f3:chararray);
replaced = foreach data generate REPLACE(f1, ',', '.') as f1dot, REPLACE(f2, ',', '.') as f2dot, REPLACE(f3, ',', '.') as f3dot;
fdata = foreach replaced generate (float)f1dot as f1, (float)f2dot as f2, (float)f3dot as f3;
dump fdata;
```

Output:

```
(1.2,2.3,4.5)
(5.6,6.7,7.8)
```

To test if it is really converted to float:

```
test = foreach fdata generate f1*f2*f3;
dump test;
```

Output:

```
(12.42)
(292.65598)
```